Mypy type error on numpy variable after multiple assignments
I am trying to determine if the following mypy warning is telling me something important.
import numpy as np
from numpy import typing as npt

def test(a: npt.ArrayLike) -> npt.NDArray:

    a = np.asarray(a)
    a = np.abs(a)

    return a

This results in the following warning on the return a line.

Incompatible return value type (got "_SupportsArray[dtype[Any]] | _NestedSequence[_SupportsArray[dtype[Any]]] | bool | int | float | complex | str | bytes | _NestedSequence[bool | int | float | complex | str | bytes]", expected "ndarray[Any, dtype[Any]]")Mypyreturn-value

Both the following work without warnings:
return np.abs(a)

b = np.abs(a)
return b

So I can't tell if there really is an issue with reassigning a to itself in np.abs or if this is one of the many subtleties of numpy typing that I should just work around.  The warning remains with many other numpy functions (np.sin,np.ceil, etc.).

Pyright correctly infers the type of ndarray and doesn't complain.
The reason the other variants worked is mypy gives up and identifies them as Any which means it typechecks any constraint.
PS: You can use typing.reveal_type to know what type the typechecker thinks an expression is.
